# Android Sdk DatePickerFragment and TextView

Tags: java, android, sdk, datepicker

i got the next problem. I want to pass the date i've entered using my `DatePickerFragment` to `TextView`, but i don't know how i can actually do it.

When i create `TextView` object in `DatePickerFragment` class and then set the text in it using `onDateSet` method - the app crashes. Maybe this question too basic, but i didn' find any suitable solution.

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment 
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

TextView tvDate1 = (TextView) getView().findViewByiD(R.id.tvDate);


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year, int month, int day){
       String

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(day);
    sb.append("/");
    sb.append(month);
    sb.append("/");
    sb.append(year);
    tvDate1.setText(sb);


}
}
```

Comment: you should post the relevant stacktrace if it's a crash. Do try the answer posted it should work

Answer (score 2):

Your app crashed probably because of this

```
   TextView tvDate1 = (TextView) getView().findViewByiD(R.id.tvDate);
```

I guess your picker is in a different file and you are trying to initialize textview. `findViewById` is a method of activity class

Use a interface

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Check the topic under communicating with activity

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    TheListener listener;

public interface TheListener{
    public void returnDate(String date);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
listener = (TheListener) getActivity(); 

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(year, month, day);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
if (listener != null) 
{
  listener.returnDate(formattedDate); 

}

}
}
```

Then in MainActivity implement the interface and set the date to textview

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DatePickerFragment.TheListener{

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DialogFragment picker = new DatePickerFragment();
                picker.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void returnDate(String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        tv.setText(date);
    }

}
```

Comment: Really thank you =) i don't know why the question got minus. Maybe my english that bad. I'm sorry about that. I learn android sdk 1st day and don't got whole picture yet. Thank's you once again m8

Comment: I've got listener object here null so nothing is displayed in my textview. Any ideas why ?

Comment: @Jalle wihtout the code its not possible to tell why