# Android Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on button and store value in variable

Tags: android, datepicker, android-calendar, android-datepicker

I'm trying to solve the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996779/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-button-and-store-value-in-vari). After the date has been chosen I wish to use it to open a browser. It should also be noted that I'm doing this work from a fragment.

I am using the second solution but am facing two problems:

1. When I press the ChooseDate button the DatePicker pops up but before I can choose the date the app already opens the browser with the old date. When I press back button I see the DatePicker and I can choose a date, and if I press the ChooseDate button again then the browser opens with almost (see 2) the desired date, and then pressing back I still see the DatePicker and so on.
2. The DatePicker returns the month with an offset of -1. E.G. I choose March and I get February. It happens both on the Emulator and on a Nexus 5 device. mCalender is a GregorianCalendar.

My questions:

1. How can I get the Calendar to stay until I choose a date and then make it go away?
2. Did anyone else encounter the wrong month supplied by the Calender (I rebuilt the App, closed and opened Android Studio), and if so, what did you do with this (other then the obvious +1 hack)

I am using Android Studio 1.1.0, API 21.

Thank you!

**Code:**

```
        mChooseDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openBrowser(CHOOSE_DAY);
        }
    });

void openBrowser(int option) {

    String date = "";

    switch (option) {
        ...

        case CHOOSE_DAY:
            chooseDate();
            date = mChosenDate;
            break;

        ...
    }


    String url = getUrl(date);

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}


...

void chooseDate() {

    int year = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(),
            new DateSetListener(), year, month, day);
    dialog.show();
}

class DateSetListener implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int chosenMonth = monthOfYear;
        int chosenDay = dayOfMonth;
        Log.i("DEBUG","chosen month: " + chosenMonth);
        updateChosenDate(chosenMonth,chosenDay);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move this:

```
String url = getUrl(date);

Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

to the method the DateSetListener calls onDateSet, so it doesn't fire before you've actually set a date.  Your current code would have it run through the switch case and start the intent without waiting on the Dialog in openBrowser().

The issue with the month could be because the calendar begins at 0 and the value being supplied is not offsetting this.  So just increment by 1.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? I'm currently looking through examples on how to achieve this and I would like to know why this is a problem?