# how to setText from value of DatePickerDialog

Tags: android, datepicker, settext, android-datepicker

Im trying to pick date after clicking on button and setting its value on TextView.
This thread helped [Datepicker: How to popup datepicker when click on button and store value in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996779/datepicker-how-to-popup-datepicker-when-click-on-button-and-store-value-in-vari)

But im unable to set value of datepicker on setText,the textview object v returns empty nullpointerexception.

```
         v.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mDay).append("/")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
        System.out.println(v.getText().toString());
```

Any help is appreciated

Full code:
Mainactivity.java

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity   {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}



public void pick(View v){

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("the selected " + mDay);
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
            new mDateSetListener(), mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dialog.show();

    }

}



     class mDateSetListener  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private TextView v;

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // getCalender();
    int mYear = year;
    int mMonth = monthOfYear;
    int mDay = dayOfMonth;
    v.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mDay).append("/")
            .append(mYear).append(" "));



}
}
```

xml file:

```
     <RelativeLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.datesamp.MainActivity" >


    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
    android:text="Pick date" 
    android:onClick="pick"/>

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/t1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
     />






     </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable *v* before using it in onDateSet(), e.g. adding the following statement before *v*.setText(...):

```
v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
v.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mDay).append("/")
            .append(mYear).append(" "));
```

But in order to insert this statement inside onDateSet(), I suggest you to define the class *mDateSetListener* as an inner class inside *MainActivity*, it will make your life easier.