# How to define date picker dialog?

Tags: android, datepicker

this is my main activity code contains error

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity{  
     static EditText bdayText;
     DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this); 
   @Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
}
```

date picker method

```
public void selectDate(View view) {

        DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");

    }
```

> ```
>   public static void setTheDate(int year, int month, int day) {
>         having error in this line
>           bdayText = (EditText)MainActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText5);
>           bdayText.setText(day+"/"+month+"/"+year);
>         }
> ```

```
 public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
     @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         int yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
         int mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
         int dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

         DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,c.YEAR, c.MONTH, c.DATE);

         dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
         dialog.setTitle("Pick a date");
         return dialog;
     }
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yy, int mm, int dd) {

         setTheDate(yy, mm+1, dd);
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672094/android-sdk-datepickerfragment-and-textview/18672134#18672134. check this and move this   `DBHandler dbHandler = new DBHandler(this)` inside `onCreate`

Comment: thanks for that link frnd.i tried that,no problem in displaying datepicker but while setting date there is some error showing in log cat java.lang.NullPointerException ..tv.setText(date); and listener.returnDate(date); .please help me in this...

Comment: you need to implement the interface define in dialog fragment, Also make sure you have initialzied textview tv in onCreate

Comment: everythng works fine frnd ,thank you.silly mistake,i have initialised textview as static ,now changed it,,,got worked..!!!.Thanks again..

Comment: if it helps you can upvote the answer in the link posted